# Display a text in right-top-corner of Bootstrap panel-body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I show a news content into Bootstrap panel
left side is image and top-right side should be date of news

```
   <div class="panel-body">
        RenderImage(x.Image)
        <div class="pull-right"  style="margin-top: 0;>
            Date()
        </div>
```

But date content is not on top-right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the content inside row and column like this.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="pull-right" style="margin-top: 0;>Date()</div>
            RenderImage(x.Image)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```